# Update an embedded document in an array - Mongodb + Node Driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to be able to: 
Find a document with a specific id, then find the document in the legacy array based off a shortID, and update the sets array of that embedded document that matched the shortID.

Clearly, something hasn't clicked for me yet.

I have the following structure:

```
  {
    "id" : "5706e5b5cbc61e5bf3a9f4e7",
    "legacy" : [
        {
            "shortID" : "B1zHAllg",
            "timeStamp" : "Apr 16th 2016",
            "sets" : [
                {
                    "weight" : "7",
                    "reps" : "7"
                },
                {
                    "weight" : "7",
                    "reps" : "7"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "shortID" : "HyUVCegx",
            "timeStamp" : "Apr 16th 2016",
            "sets" : [
                {
                    "weight" : "6",
                    "reps" : "6"
                },
                {
                    "weight" : "6",
                    "reps" : "6"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
 }
```

I have tried many options but felt I was closest with trying the following:

```
db.bench.findAndModify({query:{id:"5706e5b5cbc61e5bf3a9f4e7"},sort:{legacy:{$elemMatch:{shortID:"HyUVCegx"}}},update:{$set:{sets:[9]}}})

db.bench.update({id : "5706e5b5cbc61e5bf3a9f4e7", legacy:{$elemMatch:{shortID:"HyUVCegx"}}}, {$set : { sets: [{"weight":"5", "reps" :"10"}] }})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use positional updates for this kind of operations. See documentation for [positional updates](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Example: In MongoDB shell, you'll be doing as:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
{"legacy.shortID":"HyUVCegx"}, 
{$set:
  {"legacy.$.sets":
    [{"weight":"15", "reps" :"10"}]
  }
})
```

Query above will modify content of documents in `legacy` matching criteria where `shortID = "HyUVCegx"`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much Saleem!